# Hide SSRS chart based on multivalue parameter

Tags: reporting-services, charts, parameters, hidden, multivalue

Good Afternoon,

I have a multivalue parameter where if the last value in the array has the value "Reentry", it should always display the report.  However, if the last value in the array is not "Reentry" it should hide the chart because it doesn't apply to the other choice.  The choices are Corrections, Reentry and All. I applied the following expression to the visibility option of the target chart.

```
=IIf((Parameters!Division.Value(Parameters!Division.Count-1)="Reentry"), True, False)
```

This is showing the report for all cases, even when I select only Corrections which is the value that appears in a textbox where I placed this expression, being the last value in the array.

```
=Parameters!Division.Value(Parameters!Division.Count-1)
```

I have tried all kinds of other ways to get this to work and I have been stuck for a day.  I think this approach is the easiest but it is always showing the chart, no matter what is selected.  Any thoughts?  This shouldn't be so difficult...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression:

```
=IIF(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Division.Value,"Reentry")=
Parameters!Division.Count-1,True,False
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is still showing the reentry chart when only corrections is selected.  I copied/pasted your expression so there isn't a typo.  Also, it didn't break the report, so the expression's syntax was proper, it just didn't have any affect on the visibility...other ideas?